# Was my Macbook Pro remotely accessed?

Tags: macos, network, security, logs, remote-control

I'm running Mojave on a Macbook Pro. A while ago, my screen started randomly scrolling down by itself while I was using Safari, and the problem persisted for a few seconds. The scrolling seemed almost human, so I decided to check my system logs and found the following information:

```
Jul 13 20:20:19 MacbookPro1 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Jul 13 20:20:41 MacbookPro1 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preferences.sharing.remoteservice[8320]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by com.apple.preferences.sharing.re[8320]
Jul 13 20:20:52 MacbookPro1 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Jul 13 20:20:54 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
```

I'm not very experienced in reading system logs, but it seems that the `sharing.remoteservice` that was `SIGKILL`ed might be relevant here. I found a blog post that seems to indicate that the combination of the `sharing.re line` and the `SIGKILL` line is indicative of a remote access.

I had file sharing, screen sharing, etc. all turned off, but bluetooth was on. My firewall was also off.

From these logs and the scrolling behavior I described, does it seem like someone had unauthorized accessed my computer? If so, what should my next steps be?